# Regex c# html spider

Tags: c#, html, regex

I'm trying to have my console application return me all of these values in a html webpage:
`<img border="0" alt="img.jpg" title="img.jpg" src="/_layouts/images/icjpg.gif" />`

However I'm only interested in the `title="img.jpg"`.
I've seen that Regular expressions can be used to filter these, however I don't see how I filter the rest away and only keep `title="img.jpg"` or the value in the `title="THIS"`

Any help would be appreciated.

I've seen this [cheatlist for regex](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet)

Comment: You want the title attribute of all html tags, or just the ones of img tags ?

Comment: Have you considered using HtmlAgilityPack instead of regex? While I don't think regex is as bad for this(as long as you're only extracting information from a certain specific website) as most people claim, HtmlAgilityPack is a cleaner solution.

Comment: @CodesInChaos No I did not up to know. But I'm checking the possibilities ofcourse. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Better solution is to use HtmlAgilityPack to parse HTML.

http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Example [only img tags with border = "0"]

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(your html string);

List<String> titles = (from x in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                       where x.Name == "img"
                       && x.Attributes["title"] != null
                       && x.Attributes["border"] != null
                       && x.Attributes["border"].Value == "0"
                       select x.Attributes["title"].Value).ToList<String>();
```

This LINQ code return titles for all img tags.

Comment: Checking this out right now. However it displays me x.Attributes cannot be used like a method.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [HtmlAglityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com) from *codeplex*. Or you could try this regex

```
<img[^>]*(?<title>title=\"[^\"]+\")[^>]*>
```

and a sample code using LINQ:

```
var result = from Match match 
             in Regex.Matches(strInput, "<img[^<]*(?<title>title=\"[^\"]+\")[^<]*>")
             select match.Groups["title"].Value;
```